# Custom Sonar Rule: Require methods when class is used as a parameter to a particular method

Tags: java, sonarqube

I am trying to create a custom rule for sonarqube.

I want to search for times when a method is called for example:

```
ExClass classInstance = new ExClass();
classInstance.methodCall(a, b);
```

where methodCall is defined as:

```
public void methodCall(Object a, Object b){}
```

What I want is to verify that any class passed as an argument into methodCall() has overridden the methods equals() and hashCode().

I have already found the source code for the EqualsOverridenWithHashCodeCheck, so I can verify that classes have in fact overriden both equals and hashCode, however, I don't know how to qualify that this should /only/ be done when the class if found as an argument to methodCall.

Any suggestions?

EqualsOverrideWithHashCodeCheck source:

https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/blob/master/java-checks/src/main/java/org/sonar/java/checks/EqualsOverridenWithHashCodeCheck.java